# Running thread java

Tags: java

```
Thread thread = new Thread("New Thread") 
{
    public void run(){ 
       //instructions A,B and C
    }
};

thread.start();
//instructions D, E
```

I wonder why D and E do not run after termination of instructions A, B and C.
How do I make D and E run after instructions A, B and C finish?

Comment: I'm surprised your code compiles.

Comment: If you want sequential execution why are you using a thread? Not a real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** If you want D and E to run after the completion of the A,B and C, then you must use
       `join()`.

**2.** When join() is called on a thread, **then it waits for that thread to die(ie to finish its run() method), then execute the line after the join().**

**3.** Its better to use `CountDownLatch from java.util.concurrent` package.

Answer (score 4):

> How to make D and E run after termination of instructions A, B and C

Um, don't run A, B and C in a new thread? The whole point of kicking off a new thread is that the current thread *can* run other code while the `run()` method on the new thread runs.

You *could* call `thread.join()` before D and E... but why would you want to do that?

If you just want to run your code in the order A, B, C, D, E, then just do it all in the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

Threads run in parallel (roughly, at least). So when your thread starts instructions A, B and C run parallel to instructions D and E. If you don't want that, don't use another thread in the first place (at least that's the easiest option).

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to run afterwards, don't use a thread to execute A,B, and C.

If you want a specific order why are you using a thread?